# Use Jquery to append a field input value to the url as a query string

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, onclick, query-string

I believe I have most of this right, but may be messing up the order, and can't get a fiddle to save for some reason. Basically I need to grab part of a form Input and append it as a query string on submit so as to trigger the affiliate cookie on the next page. All codes would start with a AAA-11 value and then the actual affiliate reference code. So

```
<form>
    <label>Affiliate Code</label>   
    <input type="text" id="code">
    <input type="submit" id="submit_btn">        
</form>
```

And the JS:

```
$('#submit_btn').on('click', function() {
    var str = $('#code').val();
    var acode = str.substr(6);
    location.href = location.href + "?ref=" + acode;
});
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1):

Your button is submitting the form because of its attribute `type="submit"`

You can change the attribute to `type="button"`, or programmatically prevent form submission using [**`event.preventDefault()`**](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/), so that you can modify the data.

```
$('#submit_btn').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var str = $('#code').val();
    var acode = str.substr(6);
    location.href = location.href + "?ref=" + acode;
});
```

---

**[EDIT]** (comment)

If you need to modify the form `action` and submit the form aswell, use this:

```
$('#submit_btn').on('click', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var str = $('#code').val();
    var acode = str.substr(6);
    // change form action attribute and submit the form:
    $(this).closest('form').attr('action', location.href + "?ref=" + acode).submit();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, makes sense! But how can I still have it submit a few seconds after? Or alternatively, include the query string live as soon as the input is filled in by the user?

Comment: I'm not sure if I well understand you. Maybe something like: `if( !$('#code').val() ){ event.preventDefault() }` ?

Comment: I mean that preventDefault() will stop the submit from happening.. but I still need the form to submit.

Comment: Then you can put the `preventDefault()` in a simple `if` statement to determine whether the form should be submitted or not, just like in my previous comment. Of course the `if` condition you set is up to your needs... BTW. The input field has no `name`, so it won't be submitted anyway. Also, you can use cookies (if you need them on current page) directly in javascript. As for the JSFiddle - you can't save it when the javascript section includes `location.` code.

Comment: I understand the conditional part, but maybe then preventDefault is not the best way to do this. I want it work like so: User is on form at mysite.com/stuff, fills out affiliate code among other values, clicks submit > Query string parameter is attached so the url is now mysite.com/stuff?ref=code, then form is submitted and the parameter passed on to the confirmation page where the affiliate software pixel or script will read it as if someone had come form a standard affiliate link (the affiliate system is a third party software). Sorry If I was no clear about it earlier.

Comment: @Epleroma, updated answer, something like this? I'm not sure what is the `confirmation page` ?

Comment: Thank you! But assuming the form already has a different action, would $(this).closest('form').submit(); also work to submit it after the URL change?

Comment: It will submit the form. The question is what url it will be submitted to (as the form `action` attribute will also be updated on the next page).